# Ignore macro if it is not defined

Tags: c, compiler-errors, preprocessor

I am using the following macro in some C files:

```
DBGL_LOG_INFO(DBGL_UART_LOG_ENABLED, "UART is initialized");
```

The macro calls my logging module, if the define LOG_UART_ENABLED is true.
If the define is false, the logging code will not be compiled and so does not influence my regular program code in release build.

But now, I have the following Problem:
The C files, which does contain this macro call should be also used in another project, where the log module does not exist. So the define DBGL_UART_LOG_ENABLED also does not exist in this other Project.

Of course, when I compile the file with this code in the project, i get the following error:

```
'DBGL_UART_LOG_ENABLED' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean '...'?
```

Is it possible, to tell the compiler, that this code should be ignored, if the macro and the defines are missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionally define the macro. For instance, the following is a common pattern:

```
#ifndef DBGL_UART_LOG_ENABLED
#   define DBGL_UART_LOG_ENABLED 0
#endfif
```

And you probably also need to handle `DBGL_LOG_INFO`:

```
#ifndef DBGL_LOG_INFO
#   define DBGL_LOG_INFO(...) do {} while (false)
#endif
```

This defines the macro as an empty block that swallows its arguments. That way, you can continue to use the macro in code without it affecting the output.

Answer (score 1):

This would be why such code is commonly written as

```
#ifdef DBGL_UART_LOG_ENABLED

/* do stuff with DBGL_UART_LOG_ENABLED */

#endif
```